# Play Store not setting the values for UTM parameters in Google Campaign Receiver

Tags: android, google-analytics-campaign-builder

In my Android app, the play store is not setting the value for 
`utm_medium` and `utm_source` sometimes.

I am building my referral links using this link: `https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns`

which has the following `utm_parameter`:

```
"utm_source%3Dandroid-app%26utm_medium%3Dreferral%26utm_term%3Dreferral-message%26utm_content%3Dtamil-referral%26utm_campaign%3Din-app-referral-campaign%26anid%3Dadmob"
```

Clicking on this the URL will redirect the user to my App in play store
and when they install it, the parameters are supplied to the android app
which I handle through a broadcast receiver.
But many-a-times these params are not being set.

Any help would be great.